# How to flash protected STM8 MCU?

Tags: firmware, stm8

I would like to flash a new firmware on my STM8L15xC8. I have ST Visual Programmer (STVP) installed and can successfully flash the MCU of the STM8 Discovery board. Now, I setup the STM8 Discovery board to flash external applications. However, when I want to write to the MCU my hex file, I get the error `The device is protected`. What should I do?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Make sure that the Read Out Protection (ROP) byte is set to off. Open STVP, go to the OPTION BYTE tab, set ROP to off and write out (`Ctrl + P`). Then, go to the PROGRAM MEMORY tab again and you should be able to write your hex file.